# How to get all morphological derivations of a word in java or php

Tags: java, php

Is there any Library in Java or PHP that could help in retrieving all the derivations of some word?

Eg. happiness and unhappy from the root word happy

Thanks

Comment: Check out `WordsAPI` which you can access in Java or PHP:http://restunited.com/docs/38i3os7fk64z

Answer (score 1):

I don't know such library, it is rather a dictionary data, but I don't know also such dictionary data.

Maybe you could use a plain dictionary (list of all word and its deriviations) and find similiar words, by calculating the Levenshtein distance from your original word. I think it could work in general, but it will give you also some errors.

Here you can find the algorithm for java: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance

I have found some dictionary data hare: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/latest/

Maybe you can find out there some data you can use and adapt :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called snowball. It is a library for creating stemming algorithms. You can see a little demo here: http://snowball.tartarus.org/demo.php